# Yii2 Timezone for different users, input display

Tags: postgresql, yii2

I'm saving my records in UTC format. With the next piece of code:

```
timeZone' => 'America/Chicago'
```

I successfully changed my grid data into Chicago's timezone. The problem is every signle input and Google Chart I have.

I tried with:

```
'on afterOpen' => function($event) {
    $event->sender->createCommand("SET TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'")->execute();
}
```

But nothing!

p.s. I'm using Yii2 + postgreSQL.

Thanks.